# Not able to understand how iterator works on class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

```
from __future__ import print_function

class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, salary=0):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
    def giveRaise(self, percent):
        self.salary = self.salary + (self.salary * percent)
    def work(self):
        print(self.name, "does stuff")
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Employee: name=%s, salary=%s>" % (self.name, self.salary)


class Chef(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name) :
        Employee.__init__(self, name, 50000)

    def work(self) :
        print(self.name, "makes food")


class Server(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Employee.__init__(self, name, 40000)
    def work(self):
        print(self.name, "interfaces with customer")

class PizzaRobot(Chef):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Chef.__init__(self, name)
    def work(self):
        print(self.name, "makes pizza")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for klass in Employee, Chef, Server, PizzaRobot:
        obj = klass(klass.__name__)
        obj.work()
```

In above code I am not able to understand how last 3 lines behaves whether klass would be a class or it would be an instance of class. 
if its an class then what below line means and why it is required?

```
obj = klass(klass.__name__)
```

Comment: `klass` will be a pointer to the class, and `klass()` will create a new instance of the class...

Comment: There's no iterator over class here, you're simply looping over a tuple containing references to the class objects.

Comment: I also don't think you can do `obj = klass(klass.__name__)` because `__name__` is not initiated before `klass()` is called. Because each iteration will get a new uninitated klass handle to be called?

Comment: @Torxed this code is from Learning Python book and its working. I am just not able to understand it. :(

Comment: @Torxed Classes have `__name__` attribute too, so the code is fine.

Comment: Well the code logic is quite clear except for the `klass.__name__` part. You iterate over a list of classes, you instantiate each class into a handle, and then you call `.work()` on that class-handle. The part that boggles me a bit is why you pass `klass.__name__` since it doesn't exists until you pass `__init__()` in the class, which you do by calling the class like so `Server()`...

Comment: @200OK Ah f¤%! ofc they do -.- Yea sorry, got confused by `self.name=...`.. And suddenly the code makes perfect sense :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned there's no iterator here, but a tuple of classes. The loop below will loop over each class and instantiate a new object for each of the classes.

```
for klass in Employee, Chef, Server, PizzaRobot:
    obj = klass(klass.__name__)
    obj.work()
```

If you look at your class definitions and specifically the `__init__`-function for each class, you'll see that there's a positional argument `name`:

```
class Chef(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name): # <-- look here.
```

Which means that each of your classes must be instantiated with a parameter name:

```
>>> john = Chef('John')
>>> print(john)
<Employee: name=John, salary=50000>
```

Each *class* has a [`__name__`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) attribute, which is the defined name for that class. For example `Chef.__name__` is `Chef`:

```
>>> Chef.__name__
'Chef'
```

This is different from the `name` parameter you've defined for your classes, as this is an internal attribute and should not be changed.

Thus the line `obj = klass(klass.__name__)` will create an object for each the classes you're looping over and give the class `__name__` attribute as the positional argument `name` for each object.

You will end up with four objects of types `Employee`, `Chef`, `Server` and `PizzaRobot`. Instead of human names like `John` as per the example I've given, you're just naming them after the class.

```
>>> for klass in Employee, Chef, Server, PizzaRobot:
...     print(klass.__name__)
...    
Employee
Chef
Server
PizzaRobot
>>>
```